# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void containsKey(Id) from the type Set<Id>

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I am getting the following error on line 12 and 25 and would need some help in resolving it.

Error on line 12:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void containsKey(Id)
>   from the type Set

Error on Line 25:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(Id) from the
>   type List

```
trigger UpdateContactPhoneNumberOnCases on Contact (after update) {
List <case> affectedCases = [select id, Contact_Phone__c  from case 
                            where contactId in : trigger.newMap.keyset()];

    // A map of contact Ids -> to list of cases

    map<id, list<case>> affectedCasesByContactId = new Map<Id,List<case>>();

    // Now populate the map  (affectedCasesByContactId)

    for (case c: affectedCases) {
**12---->**        if (affectedCasesByContactId.keyset().containsKey(c.contactId)){
            affectedCasesByContactId.get(c.contactId).add(c);

        }else {
            affectedCasesByContactId.put(c.contactId, new List<case>{c});
        }

    }

// create a new list to hold our newly updated cases

    List <case> updatedcases = new List<case>();
    for (Id contactId: trigger.newMap.keyset()) {        
**25--->** if(trigger.old.get(contactId).phone != trigger.new.get(contactId).phone)
           {
            for (case thisCase: affectedCasesByContactId.get(contactId)){
            thisCase.Contact_Phone__c = trigger.new.get(contactId).phone;
            updatedcases.add(thisCase);
        }
    }

}
           try{
           update updatedcases;
           } catch (exception e){
               system.debug(e.getMessage());
           }
           }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first one, instead of:

```
affectedCasesByContactId.keyset().containsKey(...)
```

use either the Map method `containsKey` on the Map:

```
affectedCasesByContactId.containsKey(...)
```

or the Set method `contains` on the Set:

```
affectedCasesByContactId.keyset().contains(...)
```

For the second one instead of trying to access from the List:

```
trigger.new.get(...)
```

access from the Map:

```
trigger.newMap.get(...)
```

Take a look at the available [Trigger Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) and also do some Googling about lists and maps to get clear about how to use those most effectively.

Answer (score 2):

The method you're looking for is `contains()`. `containsKey()` is in `Map`, not `Set`.

Comment: Aidan, Thanks for that. It solved the error on line 12. Could you help me on line 25. The code :                                                                                                      if (trigger.old.get(contactId).phone != trigger.new.get(contactId).phone)                 Error :    Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(Id) from the type List<Contact>